# Unknown column in `where` clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error described in title:

```
Unknown column 'FeedbackType' in 'where clause'
```

But I don't understand why. This is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `Appointments`.ID, FeedbackType, FeedbackSubType 
FROM `UserFeedback`
INNER JOIN `Appointments` ON `Appointments`.ID = `UserFeedback`.Appointments_ID 
INNER JOIN `Reasons` ON `UserFeedback`.FeedbackSubType = `Reasons`.ID  
WHERE `FeedbackType` = 1  ORDER BY `Appointments`.ID ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

`FeedbackType` is a column in the `UserFeedback` table, casing is correct, checked it several times already.

For completeness, this is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserFeedback` 
(
   ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FeedbackType int(4) NOT NULL,
   FeedbackSubType int(4) NOT NULL,
   Notes varchar(170) NULL,
   Appointments_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   IpTracking_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (Appointments_ID) REFERENCES Appointments(Id), 
   FOREIGN KEY (IpTracking_ID) REFERENCES IpTracking(Id)    
)
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What could be the issue?

**[Edit]**

These variants don't work either (because `FeedbackType` does not contain reserved words/characters and belongs only to the `UserFeedback` table):

```
... WHERE UserFeedback.FeedbackType = 1
... WHERE `UserFeedback`.`FeedbackType` = 1
... WHERE FeedbackType = '1'
etc.
```

(and I actually see no reason why they should)

**[Edit 2]**

I ran `SELECT * FROM UserFeedback` to make sure it really contains the column, and I got several rows, all containing the column (well, `INSERT`s worked without errors).

For each of the mentioned variants, I always get the same error, always in the `WHERE` clause. If I omit the `WHERE` clause, I get unfiltered results (including the `FeedbackType` column in those results), so it's really confusing.

**[Solution]**

For some reason, replacing the `WHERE` query with a condition inside `INNER JOIN` fixed it, as @MarinSagovac [suggested in his second snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12877506/1488067):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `Appointments`.ID, FeedbackType, FeedbackSubType 
FROM `Appointments`
INNER JOIN `UserFeedback` ON `Appointments`.ID = `UserFeedback`.Appointments_ID 
   AND `UserFeedback`.FeedbackType = 1
INNER JOIN `Reasons` ON `UserFeedback`.FeedbackSubType = `Reasons`.ID  
ORDER BY `Appointments`.ID ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Note that there's no `WHERE` clause now, but the semantics should be the same, right? And it's clear that the column really exists, so the error message is a bit misleading IMHO.

Comment: @SOaddict: *Unknown column 'UserFeedback.FeedbackType' in 'where clause'* (or *Unknown column 'FeedbackType' in 'where clause'* if I omit table name).

Comment: Are you sure the column exists? Was the table created without the column and then you added it to the sql at a later point. If so, the "if not exists" statement will prevent it from being added. Run this `SELECT * FROM UserFeedback` and tell us what columns you see in the result.

Comment: @JLevett: yes, tried it, it exists. I ran `SELECT * FROM UserFeedback` and it returned all 6 columns. I even manually copy/pasted the column from that output into my query to make sure I wasn't (entirely) crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add backtick:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `Appointments`.ID, `FeedbackType`, `FeedbackSubType`
FROM `UserFeedback`
INNER JOIN `Appointments` ON `Appointments`.ID = `UserFeedback`.Appointments_ID 
INNER JOIN `Reasons` ON `UserFeedback`.FeedbackSubType = `Reasons`.ID  
WHERE `FeedbackType` = 1  ORDER BY `Appointments`.ID ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Added try:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `Appointments`.ID, FeedbackType, FeedbackSubType 
FROM `UserFeedback`
INNER JOIN `Appointments` ON `Appointments`.ID = `UserFeedback`.Appointments_ID 
INNER JOIN `Reasons` ON `UserFeedback`.FeedbackSubType = `Reasons`.ID  
INNER JOIN `UserFeedback`.`FeedbackType` = 1  ORDER BY `Appointments`.ID ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Well, the query works if I remove the `WHERE` clause completely, and it returns the `FeedbackType` column correctly.

Comment: Wait why you are add WHERE `FeedbackType` = 1 and want reprint this '1'? It this really need? Are you try add in WHERE clause WHERE `FeedbackType` = '1'

Comment: Maybe insted WHERE `FeedbackType` = 1  change to WHERE `UserFeedback`
.`FeedbackType` = 1 OR WHERE `UserFeedback`.`FeedbackType` = '1'

Comment: Instead WHERE which can be slowly for database use INNER JOIN FeedbackType. For example: INNER JOIN UserFeedback.FeedbackType = 1  ORDER BY `Appointments`.ID ASC

Comment: Well, I don't have a clue why, but replacing the `WHERE` clause with the condition inside `INNER JOIN` fixed it. I am in a bit of a hurry right now, so I don't have time to analyze it, but it's rather strange IMHO.

Comment: Try post and description of problematic (include stackoverflow on vendor specific database ex. mysql oracle or postgresql forum). This is very specific problem or syntax parser / confused unsolution...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to do it next week, sounds like an interesting issue.

Comment: Ok and give a result. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe found solution. If you using transcation PK/FG use `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` instead `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` because table is in transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try UserFeedback.FeedbackType in the where clause?

Comment: Try slant-quoting both table and column (can't make the slant-quotes appear in this comment): 'UserFeedback'.'FeedbackType'

Comment: @blearn: Yes, I tried that variant too. Although I hate to try things like this randomly, because a) backticks are not needed if the column is not a reserved name or contains reserved chars, and b) there is no need to specify the table unless two tables contain the same column. So, I am asking why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `Appointments`.ID, UserFeedback.FeedbackType, `UserFeedback.FeedbackSubType 
FROM `UserFeedback'
INNER JOIN `Appointments` ON `Appointments`.ID = `UserFeedback`.Appointments_ID 
INNER JOIN `Reasons` ON `UserFeedback`.FeedbackSubType = `Reasons`.ID  
WHERE UserFeedback.FeedbackType = 1  ORDER BY `Appointments`.ID ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

try it now

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key while using myisam?

that's probably the problem

Comment: There is nothing wrong with specifying foreign keys with MyISAM, but what it doesn't support are constraints. So I don't see how this would affect joining, especially since other queries work well.

Answer (score -2):

Try this in WHERE clause:

WHERE UserFeedback.FeedbackType = '1'

Remove all quotes(') in field's name

Comment: Sure, I could try this, but... why? Why do you think this would work? (I didn't downvote, btw).

Comment: Because I use with this syntax in my queries and work very well. It runs in mysql and postgres too.